# Home & Office Laptop Connection

Tags: laptop, wireless-networking, database, isp

This may be a weird question, but...I have caught my son accessing inappropriate material on my work laptop at my home. He has used my wireless hope ISP. Will that show up at work on the servers there? I've gone through and deleted everything I can find on the actual laptop itself. I'm just wondering if they really looked on their end, would they find anything? (really grumbling at my son!)

Comment: Please use edit functions in future instead of posting an answer. Also, use comments to comment on an answer.

Comment: Sorry..that is HOME ISP

Answer (score 4):

If you have to ask the question, assume that your IT folk know everything that happens on your computer and you don't know enough to purge it. Write your superior a brief note explaining what happened, what steps you took to mitigate it (gave junior a talking to, cleaned your machine to the best of your ability, that it won't happen again) get it on record.

The truth is a very powerful tool. You don't need to be embarrassed; kids will be kids. You do need to cover your proverbial self as clearly and as promptly as you can.

Comment: Also, make sure you run a anti-virus check just in case. Some pornographic/pirate sites attempt to install viruses on their visitor's computers.

Comment: Or ask your corporate IT folk to do it on your behalf, thus adding to the CYA "sincerity".